# iOS App Extension rotation breaks status bar

Tags: ios, xamarin, constraints, ios9, statusbar

I've been working on an app extension for quite some time but it seems like iOS 9 breaks the status bar when I rotate the device while using the extension.

I've made some screenshots with the simulator but it also happens on a real device.

Here's a screenshot before rotation :
[image: Before Rotation]

Here's a screenshot after rotating the device :
[image: after rotating the device]

Here's a screenshot of safari after exiting the extension :
[image: safari screenshot]

As you can see the status bar is broken and I believe this is caused by iOS 9.

Is there something I can do to fix this problem? (I don't want to disable rotation)

Comment: I tried to replicate this using my device, using the Mail extension from Safari, and wasn't able to. (iPhone 6 iOS 9.0.2)

Comment: Tried it with 9.0.2  on an iphone 4s and I'm still able to reproduce it. Mail isn't an extension when you click on it it launches the mail app.

Comment: it shows the system's mail compose window- an MFMailViewController. (This also called from the Mail app). I can't replicate your problem using a few other extensions either, I'm afraid. (Including mine, which uses a custom view)